# Apexchats Custom Tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, apexcharts

So I've been fiddling around with the custom tooltip option that Apexcharts offer but I'm not sure if it is possible to do anything like this:

[image: graph design]

I guess it would have to be aligned with the X axis and it would need to have a blurred overlay.

Is such thing possible? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @João! That, or something very similar, is definitely possible, and sounds like you're on the right track with the [custom tooltip](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/). There are plenty of Apexcharts code pens - there's a [custom tooltip one](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/NBdyvV). And here's a good pointer for [custom positioning](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/1178#issuecomment-570770570). If you get stuck on something specific, you can edit your question to focus on that issue (or ask a new one).

Comment: Hey @OscarSchafer ! Thank you so much. I've tried using that github snippet and I got the tooltip to be on the marker spot. It was very helpful!